# I need some help to change some code, gives error sometimes

Tags: sql, solarwinds-orion

I'm trying to query data (MAC addresses) in order but only show the first data found.
It works most of the time but I guess it gives me an error when multiple MAC addresses are found? Is there a way to make this code work?

The error I get:

> MACRO SQL ERROR - Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

The language SWQL does not exist in stackoverflow and I can't add it so I chose SQL-server but it's basically the same.

```
select coalesce((select (MAC) 
from NodeMACAddresses 
where NodeID=$@nodeid@), NULLIF('${MAC_Address}', ''), 'MAC address missing')
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. Seems you have some rows in `NodeMACAddresses ` with the same value for `NodeID`.

Comment: It's definitely *not* the same. SQL Server is a product, with its own SQL dialect. Each database product has its own dialect. What product are you using and what is `SWQL`? If the tag doesn't exist, it's clear that people *don't* know about it. You'll have to explain what it is, which product uses it, preferably with links

Comment: And yes, the error is clear. If the inner query returns more than one result, you'll get an error from any function that expects a *single* result like `COALESCE`. The query is probably a bad idea too - the result should contain a `MAC` address or nothing. Mixin up real results with messages will only introduce bugs and confuse client-side code.

Comment: According to a google, "SWQL" is "Solarwinds Query Language" ([Use SolarWinds Query Language (SWQL) in the Orion Platform](https://support.solarwinds.com/SuccessCenter/s/article/Use-SolarWinds-Query-Language-SWQL)), so I've added that as a tag for now.

Comment: The best option would be to run just `select MAC 
from NodeMACAddresses 
where NodeID=$@nodeid@` and modify the client code to handle multiple or no results.

Comment: @Larnu Yes that is correct, I didn't have enough reputation so I could not add a tag myself, thank you.

Comment: That tag already existed, @Spifa .

Comment: @Larnu Hmm maybe I searched for the solarwinds language SWQL, can't remember.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround to this could be:

```
select coalesce((select top 1 (MAC) 
from NodeMACAddresses 
where NodeID=$@nodeid@), NULLIF('${MAC_Address}', ''), 'MAC address missing')
```

Now your subquery will always return at most 1 row, and solve your problem. But this will work only until you want to show only 1 of the existing MAC address for each node.

Comment: I get MACRO SQL ERROR - Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.

Comment: try select coalesce((select top 1 (MAC) 
from NodeMACAddresses 
where NodeID=$@nodeid@), NULLIF('${MAC_Address}', ''), 'MAC address missing')